# Weird sql error, calling a something a column that isn't a column

Tags: sql, string, select, where-clause

I have an sql statement that looks like this:
`SELECT name FROM companies WHERE name = government;`

But then the error says this: `Unknown column 'government' in 'where clause',`

[image]

But anyway, why is this happening? I've been stuck on it for 30 minutes and simply putting `SELECT name FROM companies` will work (no error).

Comment: Did you mean to say: where name = 'government' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm used to using pdo statements in php and I forgot that you can't treat strings the same way as integers.

Comment: That's ok. I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compare a column against a literal string - for this, you need to surround the string with single quotes, otherwise the database takes it as a column name. So:

```
SELECT name FROM companies WHERE name = 'government';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes `'` around `government`

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM companies 
WHERE name = 'government';
```